# I need to display a student's numerical mark in a class as well as their letter grade. My code does not output the letter. How can I fix this?

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
class finalGrade
{
    //declare variables
    String name;
    double quizTotal = 0;
    double midterm = 0;
    double exam = 0;
    double mark = 0;
    char grade;


    //initialize variables
    public finalGrade (String nameStudent, double quizMark, double midtermMark, double examMark)
    {
        name = nameStudent;
        quizTotal = quizMark;
        midterm = midtermMark;
        exam = examMark;
    }

    public double marks()
    {
        mark = ((exam * 0.25) + (midterm * 0.25) + (quizTotal * 0.50));

        System.out.println((name) + ", your mark is " + (mark) + " and you get a(n) " + (grade));

        if (mark >= 90)
        {
            return (grade) = 'A';
        }
        else if (mark >= 80 && mark < 90)
        {
            return (grade) = 'B';
        }
        else if (mark >= 70 && mark < 80)
        {
            return (grade) = 'C';
        }
        else if (mark >= 60 && mark < 70)
        {
            return (grade) = 'D';
        }
        else if (mark < 60)
        {
            return (grade) = 'F';
        }
        else
        {
            return (grade) = 'F';
        }


    }
}



class finalGradeTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    InputStreamReader inStream = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader sub = new BufferedReader(inStream);

    finalGrade Student1 = new finalGrade("Student", 89, 100, 21);
    finalGrade Student2 = new finalGrade("Student", 34, 21, 9);
    finalGrade Student3 = new finalGrade("Student", 89, 100, 21);
    finalGrade Student4 = new finalGrade("Student", 89, 100, 21);
    finalGrade Student5 = new finalGrade("Student", 89, 100, 21);

    Student1.marks();
    Student2.marks();

    }

}
```

This is supposed to calculate the mark, two tests worth 25%, and an exam worth 50%. It works fine for the calculations but when displaying the letter grade it is blank. I do not know how to fix this. The output I get when I run the code is:
Student, your mark is 74.75 and you get a(n)
Student, your mark is 24.5 and you get a(n)

It does not display the letter grade.

Comment: You should print after you have set a value to `grade`, not before .To do that, consider replacing your statements e.g `return (grade) = 'A';` to `grade = 'A';` .

Comment: Just a heads up naming convention in Java for classes usually start with a capital letter.

Comment: If I remove the return part of the code, I get the error: missing return statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's because you return the mark, instead of including ot on the System.out
also, no need to re-verify if mark is <90, as otherwise it would be an A.

Also, class name have uppercase while variable have lowercase

```
import java.io.*;
class FinalGrade
{
    //declare variables
    String name;
    double quizTotal = 0;
    double midterm = 0;
    double exam = 0;
    double mark = 0;
    char grade;


    //initialize variables
    public FinalGrade (String nameStudent, double quizMark, double midtermMark, double examMark)
    {
        name = nameStudent;
        quizTotal = quizMark;
        midterm = midtermMark;
        exam = examMark;
    }

    public void marks()
    {
        mark = ((exam * 0.25) + (midterm * 0.25) + (quizTotal * 0.50));

        if (mark >= 90)
        {
            grade = 'A';
        }
        else if (mark >= 80)
        {
            grade = 'B';
        }
        else if (mark >= 70)
        {
            grade = 'C';
        }
        else if (mark >= 60)
        {
            grade = 'D';
        }
        else
        {
            grade = 'F';
        }

        System.out.println((name) + ", your mark is " + (mark) + " and you get a(n) " + (grade));




    }
}



class finalGradeTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    InputStreamReader inStream = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader sub = new BufferedReader(inStream);

    FinalGrade student1 = new FinalGrade("Student", 89, 100, 21);
    FinalGrade student2 = new FinalGrade("Student", 34, 21, 9);
    FinalGrade student3 = new FinalGrade("Student", 89, 100, 21);
    FinalGrade student4 = new FinalGrade("Student", 89, 100, 21);
    FinalGrade student5 = new FinalGrade("Student", 89, 100, 21);

    student1.marks();
    student2.marks();

    }

}
```

Comment: This still gives the error: java:57: missing return statement

Comment: @BrennanC You're right, I forget to make marks() void as he return nothing

Comment: Ah, that fixed it, thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: @BrennanC if my answer helped you, you can [accept answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved.Once you got 15 reputation, you could also upvote question and answer that help you

Answer (score 0):

You are printing before computing the `grade`. Also, there is no need to return anything here.

```
public double marks()
{
    mark = ((exam * 0.25) + (midterm * 0.25) + (quizTotal * 0.50));

    if (mark >= 90)
    {
        grade = 'A';
    }
    else if (mark >= 80 && mark < 90)
    {
        grade = 'B';
    }
    else if (mark >= 70 && mark < 80)
    {
        grade = 'C';
    }
    else if (mark >= 60 && mark < 70)
    {
        grade = 'D';
    }
    else if (mark < 60)
    {
        grade = 'F';//This must be E
    }
    else
    {
        grade = 'F';
    }
    System.out.println((name) + ", your mark is " + (mark) + " and you get a(n) " + (grade));

}
```

Also, there is no reason to compute `mark` and `grade` each time the method is called. You can compute the grade with a private method and call it from the constructor.